# iphonesdk dialing a number form a function

Tags: iphone, ios4

```
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"tel:212-555-1234" ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

i m dialing this number from a function . the problem is that it takes me away from my app, and after i dialed a number i cannot get on the state of application which i was at . how can i get back to my app after i finished dialing. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Thats outside the scope of your application.

Comment: so is that means that i cannot insert a functionality of dialing in my app?

Comment: Exactly, unless your having some form of internetcalling function, like Skype. That way, you can stay inside your app. That means the 'Phone'-function of the iPhone is still not used, unless you get out of the app.

Comment: i think if any way i can hold the application state . than may be this will be possible. application did finish with option may do tricks ?

Comment: You should save your state before you call `openURL`.